# Java netbeans Can't add platforms

Tags: exception, netbeans, jar

I'm getting an exception when I try to run my Netbeans .jar file in a Windows 7 cmd line:
    C:\Users\Ed Sowell\Documents\NetBeansProjects\EditJudgeAssignments\dist>java -jar EditJudgeAssignments.jar

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: 
editjudgeassignments/EditJudgeAssignments : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
```

From other similar questions here I suspect it's because of differing JREs between what Netbeans generates and what my environment wants. Problem is, when I try to Add another Java Platofrm, e.g., jre6 or jre7, both of which are on my machine,  the only Java platform choice that i'm allowed to use in the one I'm already using jdk1.8.0_05.

BTW, if I try to run it by clicking on the jar file in Windows Explorer I get an Exception error dialog.

BTW, I'm a newbie to Java, having installed Neatbeans 7.4 only last week. My project does run in the IDE, and while there are a couple compiler warnings there are no errors.

TIA

Ed

Comment: What version of Java are you getting at the command line? (run `java -version`)

Answer (score 0):

To add a new Java platform to NetBeans, you need to have installed the appropriate version of the JDK (not the JRE) on the system. It sounds like you only have one JDK installed, and one or possibly two JREs installed.

First, [download the version of the JDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html) you want to target.

Next, install it, being careful to (1) not overwrite your existing JDK, and (2) choosing not to intall the additional JRE. The second point is to get just the JDK installed. If you also want to install more than one JRE, go for it, but you'll have to sort out how to point to the appropriate one when you want it.

Next, in NetBeans, click on `Tools`|`Java Platforms`. In the dialog that comes up, click on `Add Platform...`, choose `Java Standard Edition` and click `Next >`, and then navigate to the directory of the JDK you installed above. When you get to the right spot, NetBeans will recognize it as a JDK directory, and re-enable the Next button. Click on it.  Next, give it a meaningful name, and if you want point to the sources and docs. Click `Finish`.

Back in your project, the new Java platform should be available in the project properties.

Comment: OK, I went to Oracle and went to Archives to find Java SE runtime 6.45 (as I recall). Installed it. BTW, I had done that earlier today. The Netbeans IDE still does not allow adding any Java platform other that the jdk1.8.0_05. If I select either jre7 or jre 6 the next button is grayed out. I see no Java Standard Edition choice.

Comment: Reading your note again I see you say to first dl the wanted version of JRE and install it. No mention of installing another JDK, even as you mention "only 1 JDK" in your 1st paragraph.

Comment: My mistake. Meant to type JDK. Not JRE

Comment: Thanks, Robert! Turned out that the default for my Netbeans installation was 8, rather than 7, so after downloading JRE SE 8 the library issues went away.